# Simulate Network Latency on Solaris

Tags: networking, solaris

I am looking for a tool for Solaris that can simulate Network Latency, and possibly have the capability of dropping a certain percentage of packets. I have been googling this for a bit, and I came across an interesting blog post about `hxbt`, a driver for solaris:

http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/archives/6625-Less-known-Solaris-features-hxbt-or-WAN-emulation.html

It looks like this driver could be really useful to me, but I can't find any more information about it when I click through to the link that the blog entry says I should go to to get it:

http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/download/Community+Group+networking/WebHome/hxbt.tar.gz

Seems like it might have been scrapped?

Does anybody else have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog entry has a working link to a tar ball that has the precompiled driver that runs on Opensolaris: https://blogs.oracle.com/yousuf/entry/wansimulator. It does require Crossbow, though, i.e. you have to run either Opensolaris (now a defunct project) or try it with Solaris 11.